# how i can Filter to Log Error and Debug in different index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I have serilog configuration in app setting file and wanted the separate index for Error and Debug/information/verbose/fatal/warning. So i had created sub loggers and added the sinks for elastic search but errors are still logging into the index "test-" which suppose to not log error, and nothing is logging in to "testerror-" index which suppose to log error.

Can someone advise how i can resolve this issue.

"Serilog": {

```
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "debug",
        "Override": {
            "System": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {"Name": "Logger",
            "Args": {
                "configureLogger": {
                    "MinimumLevel": {
                        "Default": "Verbose" 
                    },
                    "Filter": [
                        {
                            "Name": "ByExcluding",
                            "Args": {
                                "expression": "StartsWith(Level, 'Error')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "WriteTo": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Elasticsearch",
                            "Args": {
                                "nodeUris": "http://localhost:9200",
                                "indexFormat": "test-log",
                                "templateName": "template"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Logger",
            "Args": {
                "configureLogger": {
                    "MinimumLevel": {
                        "Default": "Error" 
                    },
                    "Filter": [
                        {
                            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                            "Args": {
                                "expression": "StartsWith(Level, 'Error')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "WriteTo": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Elasticsearch",
                            "Args": {
                                "nodeUris": "http://localhost:9200",
                                "indexFormat": "testerror-log",
                                "templateName": "error-template"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

]